# Python how to find and replace unknown part or string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

lets say i have a string, where i know the format, but have variables within, how can i remove the format? Ex:

```
s = """
<%Hello%>
<%foo%>
<%Example%>
<no
>%change
here%>
"""
print(s.replace("<%*%>", "&it works&"))
```

Output:

```
>   &it works&
    &it works&
    &it works&
    <no
    >%change
    here%>
```

Comment: [`<%.*?%>`](https://regex101.com/r/5GHfbC/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """
<%Hello%>
<%foo%>
<%Example%>
<no
>%change
here%>
"""
print(re.sub("<%(.*?)%>", "&it works&", s))
```

**Output:**

```
&it works&
&it works&
&it works&
<no
>%change
here%>
```